# Software to fully simulate machine language instructions (8051)

Tags: simulation, debugging, microcontroller

I'm looking for software that can simulate results of binary code from an 8051 processor and that allows me to step through my program.

I thought the following software was perfect:

[image: Emulator 8051 1.00 TS Controls]

But that's until it couldn't validate Intel HEX checksums correctly nor could it process the MUL (multiply) command correctly. In fact, the program would continue whether the checksum is correct or not.

I'm looking for software like this from the same era since I still use an older computer with a built-in parallel port in which I do my chip programming with. Something that works for Windows 3.x/95 would be nice. Something that works in Linux would even be better.

I don't care if the screen arrangement is different, just as long as I can step through each instruction and see values stored in both memories as well as in all registers as well as the timing.

The reason I need the simulator is because then it would save me time from having to burn the contents onto the chip every time I make a minor change to my code.

The code types I can provide to the program someone recommends me are of the format BIN, HEX  and a51 (assembly).